# Lollipop WebView text wrapping

Tags: android, webview, android-5.0-lollipop, chromeview

I've used **Android WebView** component in many projects, but after updating to lollipop I have a major problem:

Pinch zooming text the **will not re-wrap** it, it just zooms in!

What can I do to re-enabled this feature which was working pretty well on KitKat and below?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, tested on Sony Xperia Z, Android 5.0.1.

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```